# to find basis of homomorphism

Tags: vector-spaces, continuous-homomorphisms

Compute $Hom(V,W)$ and also determine its dimension over $F$ where $V$ and $W$ are vector spaces over the Field $F$
given that $V=\mathbb R^2, W=\mathbb R^2, F=\mathbb R$

I have done this:
$V=\{v1=(1,0) , v2 = (0,1)\}, W=\{w1=(1,0) , w2 = (0,1)\}$

$V= a(v1)+b(v2)$ where $a,b$ belongs to $F$
then $a(v1)+b(v2) = (x,y)$
implies  $a=x , b =y$.
Now, we need to calculate $T11 ,T12 , T21 ,T22$.
So, $T11(V) = a(w1)=x(1,0)$
similarly, $T12 =a(w2),
T21=b(w1),
T22=b(w2)$.

Is this correct? If not, please help.

Comment: Are you sure it says $F=\mathbb R^2$ because that is not a field. Also you'd be better off to explain what you have done, e.g. what do you mean when you write $V=a(v1)+b(v2)$?

Comment: @Hirshy, sorry here F = R and i have represented vector space V in terms basis v1 and v2.

Comment: Do you know every F-morphism gives you a $ 2 \times 2$ matrix ?

Comment: yes...@Arpit Kansal

Answer (score 0):

Hint (building on the comment of Arpit Kansal):

given vector spaces $\mathcal V,\mathcal W$ over a field $F$ with $\dim(\mathcal V)=n,\dim(\mathcal W)=m$ there exists an isomorphism $\operatorname{Hom}(\mathcal V,\mathcal W)\rightarrow F^{m\times n}$. The proof for this relies basically on the fact, that every linear map $\varphi:\mathcal V\rightarrow\mathcal W$ can be identified with a matrix (you can also check out [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_map#Matrices) for more information on that).